# How to create an infinite carousel horizontal scroll bar in android?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

In my android app, I have a horizontal scroll bar, and I can scroll all the way to the left and right. Go too far and you can't scroll anymore.

How can I change it that, you can keep scrolling left or right for as long as you want. Basically when u see the last thing in the horizontal scroll, then if you keep scrolling, you see the first item, and it loops like this. Similarly if you scroll to the left after seeing the first item, you see the last item.

Is this possible to do in android?

Thanks

Comment: I did this for vertical scroll bar having 8 fixed views..when view 1 goes out to top it appears from bottom..but I don't know how to do that for horizontal scroll bar.I used https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/checkout and made some changes.

Comment: Try this way https://github.com/satansly/InfiniteScrollView

Comment: Take a look at this it will help you.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html